# How to align tikzpicture by their axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have multiple bar diagrams and I would like to align them so that all bars begin at the same point - how would I go about achieving such a thing?

**Edit:** One thing I missed to mention is that there are other elements in between. I edited the MWE accordingly. Maybe to make it more clear: It is used to show the results of a questionnaire. So the format is heading -> enumerated list -> heading -> graph -> heading -> enumerated list -> heading -> graph and so on

What I want:

[image]

<sup>*Left red line is the begin of `\textwidth` and right is showing the alignment*</sup>

What I have:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=newest,
   axispower/.style={
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt,
    ytick=data
  }
}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Notification-System} \label{results1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\subsubsection{Notification-System 2} \label{results2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web-Notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it have to be two `tikzpicture`s? If not, I'd suggest a `groupplot`. (See `pgfplots` manual or examples here on the site.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. not necessarily but there have to be elements in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the style of the labels so that they all have a minimum width wider than the largest of all.

```
 yticklabel style={text width=28mm,align=right},
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\axispower}{
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    yticklabel style={text width=28mm,align=right},
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web,Web-Notification}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web-Notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

You can place them in the same `tikzpicture` environment. And the second `axis` environment a few centimeters lower, here 3.5cm.

```
%\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification},yshift=-3.5cm]
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\axispower}{
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web},local bounding box=premiere]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
%\end{tikzpicture}
%
%\vspace{1cm}
%
%\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification},yshift=-3.5cm]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web-Notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Unfortunately, I forget to mention that there are elements in between (see Edit)

Comment: @leonheess If these elements are text, it is possible to insert them with the operation `\node`.

Comment: Maybe to make it more clear: It is used to show the results of a questionnaire. So the format is heading -> enumerated list -> heading -> graph -> heading -> enumerated list -> heading -> graph and so on

Comment: @leonheess There, by changing the style of the `yticklabel`, everything is aligned.

Answer (score 6):

A quick fix is to use

```
\hspace{3cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
```

for both `tikzpicture`s. `trim axis left` sets the bounding box of the `tikzpicture` such that its left edge is at the left edge of the `axis`, not including labels. The horizontal space is there to make sure the labels doesn't go into the left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=newest,
   axispower/.style={
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Notification-System} \label{results1}
\hspace{3cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\subsubsection{Notification-System 2} \label{results2}
\hspace{3cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web-Notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Old answer

A `groupplot` environment, from the `pgfplots` library `groupplots`, is intended for cases where you need multiple axes aligned in a grid, which is essentially what you're doing here. It's fairly straight forward, use a `groupplot` environment instead of `axis`, set the number of rows and columns in the grid with `group style={group size=1 by 2}` (here you can also set the space between axes, and other things), add the common `axis` options afterwards. Start each new axis with `\nextgroupplot[<local settings for this axis>]`.

In the code below I also made `axispower` a style instead of a macro, which I think makes more sense.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,showframe}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=newest,
   axispower/.style={
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
     group style={group size=1 by 2},
     axispower
]

\nextgroupplot[symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};

\nextgroupplot[symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification}]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web-Notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The frame in the screenshot is from the `showframe` package, which indicates the text block.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Unfortunately, I forget to mention that there are elements in between (see Edit)

Comment: @leonheess I see. That is indeed a rather important requirement. I just edited my answer with one possible method for that case.

Comment: That's perfect! Just one thing: I'm using `ytick=data` because of [weird stuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522775/why-is-only-every-other-symbolic-axis-coord-showing-up/522782#522782) and with your solution for some reason the symbolic coords are disappearing with that option. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @leonheess With `ytick=data` you only get yticks from the datapoints in the *first* `\addplot`. Hence, by adding `ytick=data` to the code above, only the top tick appears. In that case, try `ytick distance=1` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution: Put your two `axis` in one `tikzpicture` environment and use `anchor` option to align them.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\axispower}{
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  [\axispower,
   symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web},
   name=top plot,]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
%\end{tikzpicture}

%\vspace{1cm}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  \axispower, 
  symbolic y coords={Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web-Notification},
  anchor=north west,
  at={(top plot.below south west)},
  yshift=-5mm]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web-Notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, I suppose that the `top plot` bounding box does not contain the texts, right? The anchors are on the left side of the bars.

Comment: @Sigur, If I understand you right, yes. No need `anchor=north west` option, but now the `yshift` option take a more high value than -5mm, such as -30mm.