# Why is only every other symbolic axis coord showing up?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates, axis

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=newest,
   axispower/.style={
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt,
  }
}
\begin{document}

\section{Notification-System} \label{results1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,Email,SMS,Web,Carrier pigeon}]
  \addplot coordinates {(230,Carrier pigeon) (68,Web) (22,SMS) (50,Email) (52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively `ytick distance=1`, which works better for the case when not all symbolic coords are present in the first `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=newest,
   axispower/.style={
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt,
    ytick distance=1  % <-- added
  }
}
\begin{document}

\section{Notification-System} \label{results1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,Email,SMS,Web,Carrier pigeon}]
  \addplot coordinates {(230,Carrier pigeon) (68,Web) (22,SMS) (50,Email) (52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `ytick=data` to the `axispower` style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=newest,
   axispower/.style={
    xbar,
    y axis line style={ opacity=0 },
    axis x line=none,
    tickwidth=0pt,
    xmin=0,
    y=20pt,
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt,
    ytick=data, %       <-- added
  }
}
\begin{document}

\section{Notification-System} \label{results1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axispower, symbolic y coords={Chat,Email,SMS,Web,Carrier pigeon}]
  \addplot coordinates {(230,Carrier pigeon) (68,Web) (22,SMS) (50,Email) (52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```